# How to extract text "PLAY" from image Opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried all opencv samples. but i could not able to extract "PLAY" from the image.

Opencv Samples are working with other words.

Can anyone tell how to extract text from the image?

[image]

Comment: If it is sure that in your case, the "play" button is always yellow, then extract this colour using color segmentation and then find the word "play" in it.

Comment: Use cv2.inRange() to find the yellow. Then filter further on contours to get the word play